# Pseudo random variable set

Tags: random, hash, mapping

I would like to produce same sets of pseudorandom numbers with variable attributes from one seed.
Code is not needed, some kind of logical process would be enough.
Thanks

Long version:
I have a seed (number, numbers, string, whatever) from which I want generate sets of pseudorandom numbers for which I can set some attributes, like interval, count.
Yes, it looks like hash, but how to get variable sets from it? Some sort of mapping, perhaps?
Yes, all computer generated numbers are pseudorandom.

EDIT:
Let me add some example pseudocode to, hopefully, make myself clearer:

```
generateNumberSet(seed, min, max, count){
...;
return set;
}

generateNumberSet(159357, 0, 100, 8);
Output: 5, 34, 45, 48, 61, 74, 85, 99  

generateNumberSet(159357, 500, 1000, 5);
Output: 648, 691, 784, 821, 987  

generateNumberSet(something, 0, 100, 8);
Output: 16, 29, 48, 56, 68, 72, 82, 90  

generateNumberSet(something, 0, 100, 5);
Output: 16, 29, 48, 56, 68  

generateNumberSet(159357, 0, 100, 8);
Output: 5, 34, 45, 48, 61, 74, 85, 99
```

Comment: Not sure where you are stuck. Random number generators have a seed method which you can call, for example with the hash of your "settings" (assuming "settings" is a string).

Comment: No, settings are settings, like I described them. Some constraints on output sets.

Comment: You didn't really describe settings. For me, settings looks like the seed. What do you mean with constraints? Sorry the question is unclear. Also, what programming language is it? That would allow to provide example code.

Comment: I tought I did. "some attributes, like interval, count" And what I mean by that is, that the program should generate set of numbers, that satisfy some things, like they should  by from 0 to 100 or be all even or something else. These parameters should be changeable, but with same seed and same parameters it has to return the same set of numbers. Programing language is irrelevant to me. You can provide example in any language You prefer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to edit your question and describe exactly what those settings are. Remember, all we know about your problem is what you tell us. What you've provided so far is not sufficient to provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: So what's the problem? You seed the random number generator with the seed you provide, and generate `count` random numbers between `min` and `max`. Which part of that are you having trouble with? Do you know how to seed the RNG? Do you know how to generate numbers between `min` and `max`? Are you having trouble with a particular language?